# Getting value of Ticks in a Midi file

Tags: ios, objective-c, midi

I have a Midi File and I am Parsing that Midi file with the help of `AudioToolbox` framework, I am able to parse the file and get the information like `MIDINoteMessage` and `MIDIRawData` but to play the file, I need the information of `Ticks` which I am not getting in `MIDINoteMessage`. In `MIDINoteMessage` I am only getting the duration.

So my question is How would I get the Ticks value from the Midi File ?

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: It looks as if the `MusicTrack` knows about the `MusicTimstamp` of each event.

Comment: @CL, you mean to say While creating a `MusicTrack` with the help of that duration which i will pass on as  `MusicTimstamp`, I will be able to play that file ?

Comment: Don't you already have the track? How exactly are you parsing the file?

Comment: @CR I got your point, thanks for your suggestion it is working now, If you wish to add this as an answer please add I will accept that answer.

Comment: I don't actually know AudioToolbox; I just looked a documentation page. You'll have to write the answer yourself … 